# Sync Google Reminders with calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, google

There any way / program for synchronization Google Reminders, which use for Google Now, with calendar?

I need this because I have cloud calendar (btw this cloud on the google too :) and so uncomfortable when Google Reminders saves data only local on my device (phone and watch).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is covered in the same way that [Inbox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inbox_by_Gmail) app covered reminders. According to [this document,](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084663?hl=en) these events should show up in your calendar. Have you updated your [calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar&hl=en) app?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried Inbox and I have updated calendar app. Calendar get data from the cloud service xxx@gmail.com and from local Google Reminders, it's call "SyncML Orphaned". But it shows only in calendar on the device. I need to synchronize local calendar (SyncML Orphaned) with cloud (xxx@gmail.com). I want that local calendar upload on the cloud because I have more devices which use cloud calendar (iPad for example) and as you can understand there no information from my phone with local calendar (SyncML Orphaned) because it doesn't synchronize with cloud calendar.